# multiple key to sort array

Tags: iphone

I have NSMutableArray in which all object is in NSMutableDictionary i want to sort this array base on  NSMutableDictionary  with two key one is country and another is name.

Can any one Help me to use NSSort class to sort the array using multiple key.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're really talking about, but I think you want something like a question I've just had answered:

[NSDictionary split into two arrays (objects and keys) and then sorted both by the objects array (or a similar solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785778/nsdictionary-split-into-two-arrays-objects-and-keys-and-then-sorted-both-by-the)

Does that help at all? I haven't yet tested that answer, but it seems to be quite logical.